# What is the correct frame size for me?

Tags: frames

Well I want to buy this used giant escape 3 for a good price but the frame size seems to be a bit big. It is a shame though, Because it's at a great price. I am 5'7 and the Frame size is 23 inches. The previous owner says is also 5'7 and it fit her perfectly. Would it be a mistake if I bought this bike.?

Comment: A bike that is the wrong size is never a great price. My guess is its too big, but you have to ride it to see. Go to the LBS and try various sized bikes to get an idea what size suits you.

Comment: This is impossible to answer over Stackexchange since it depends on your body - you have to try the bike and see if it fits you. Since you say its too big, it sounds like it is the wrong size and would be a mistake to buy. For what its worth, according to the 2014 Giant Escape 3 page, the standover for a 23" frame is 31.9 inches which would be way too much for most people who are 5'7" (I am 5'11" and thats about the acceptable standover for me).

Comment: A very basic/crude rule is that, *on an old-fashioned frame where the top bar is horizontal*, you should be able to stand flat-footed over the bike with about two inches of air between the top bar and the stuff above the top bar.  (On the more typical "modern" frame with a slant bar you have to imagine where the horizontal bar would be.)  But this only gets you in the right ballpark.

Answer (score 2):

[Frame sizing is a somewhat complicated issue.](http://sheldonbrown.com/frame-sizing.html) Basically, the only way to know for sure if any bike will fit you is to give it a test ride. This is especially true of one that is questionable from the get-go. There are two big reasons for this:

1. Different people have different proportions. Just because someone is the same height as you doesn't necessarily mean that you'll both ride the same size frame.
2. Different bikes have different geometries. This means that two bikes that are both the same size may fit you differently.

If you're unable to test ride it, measure your [standover height](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_st-z.html) and compare it to the [bike's specs](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-us/bikes/model/escape.3/14810/75681/#geometry). This won't give you a certain answer about whether or not it *will* fit, but it will tell you if it definitely *won't* fit. If the standover height is too high, the bike will never fit. But if the standover height is ok, you can usually (but not always) make changes elsewhere (different length or angle in the stem, [different seatpost offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seatpost#Offset.2FLayback), etc.) to make the bike fit reasonably well. Again, you really need to test ride it to be sure.